# Exception forwarding from BackgroundWorker to Main Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, backgroundworker

What is the best way to catch Exceptions occured in BackgroundWorker in main application thread. I have intensive UPD operations being processed in BackgroundWorker, but when exception occurs, my main application can not log what happened. Please recommend the best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, which will be fired on your main application thread.

`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` will contain the exception, or will be null if there was no exception.